# Backend not updating after first tap and grabbing previous value after sequential taps

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, boolean, firebase

I am working on a "to do" app in Swift and using Firebase as my backend.

On the first tap on my checkbox to signal that a task has been done, the UI updates and the variable should become true (a checkmark appears) but firebase and the local instance of the bool value for that item do not update to false. After a second tap, the UI continues to have normal functionality (the checkmark disappears); but firebase and the local instance both update to true. Following taps from then on are reversed (True for no checkmark and false for checkmark). When I stop the simulator in Xcode and re-run, the values and UI that load in are correct. It is not until I try and tap on the checkmark that I get the incorrect functionality again. Firebase only updates after the second tap and change in UI. I have include just the code that pertains to the checkbox. I think the problem happens in the `doneHit` function but I am not quite sure why its happening.

Please help. If there is an easier way to go about this, that would be helpful too.

```
protocol TaskCellDelegate {
    func doneHit(cell : TaskCell)
}

class TaskCell : UITableViewCell {

    var delegate : TaskCellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBox: CheckBox!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        checkBox.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }


    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        delegate?.doneHit(self)

    }

}


class CheckBox: UIButton {

    //images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checkedbox")
    let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "uncheckedbox")


    //bool propety
    var isChecked:Bool = false{
        didSet {
            if isChecked == true{
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
            else {
                self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }



    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        if(sender == self){
            if isChecked == false {
                isChecked = true
            } else {
                isChecked = false
            }
        }
    }


}

func doneHit(cell:TaskCell) {
        if let ip = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
            var task = tasks[ip.row]
            task.done = cell.checkBox.isChecked
            if task.done == true {
                task.completedBy = "Completed by: \(self.user)"
                cell.label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            }
            else {
                task.completedBy = ""
                cell.label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }
            let taskNameRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("tasks/\(task.title)")
            let completedByData = ["completedBy": "\(self.user)"]
            let doneData = ["done": task.done]
            taskNameRef.updateChildValues(completedByData)
            taskNameRef.updateChildValues(doneData)

        }
    }
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        let idx = tasks[indexPath.row]
        if let label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel {
            label.text = idx.title
            if idx.done == true {
            label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            } else {
            label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }
            if let checkBox = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? CheckBox {
                checkBox.isChecked = idx.done
            }
            if let userCompleted = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UILabel {
                if idx.done == true {
                    userCompleted.text = "Completed By: \(idx.completedBy)"
                }
                else {
                    userCompleted.text = ""
                }
            }
        }
        print("Task.done is: \(idx.done)")
        print("isChecked is:\(cell.checkBox.isChecked)")
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Your Checkbox and cell both have an action for buttonClicked, but you should not rely on the order in which they are called. I'm guessing this is the problem.

Comment: any recommendations as to what I could do? I am only having this issue because I had to switch from Parse to Firebase. I haven't changed any of the logic in the cell or checkbox class since it was on Parse (where it worked fine). The only thing I've changed is the doneHit method and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Your CheckBox class could broadcast its own notifications for "checked" and "unchecked", and then then cell could listen for those instead. Then you will be sure of the sequence, as the CheckBox will respond to `buttonClicked:` first, and then it will raise checked/unchecked. However, this is not necessarily the cause of your problem, it just looks a likely candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself after 3 days. I scrapped the Checkbox class and turned the checkbox into a UIImageView and added a gesture recognizer. The rest was just moving the Checkbox logic into the TaskTVC class under the doneHit method.